# Efficient batch inserts with blobs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, blob

I am trying to run 1,000,000 inserts with blob data for a performance test.  My pgscript code below appears to be very slow.  It has now been executing for over 17 hours in pgAdmin3.

```
DECLARE @I; -- Variable names begin with a @
SET @I = 1; -- @I is an integer
WHILE @I <= 1000000
BEGIN

INSERT INTO public.waveform(samplecount, typename, typeid, samples, compressed, topicsessionid, starttimeutc, endtimeutc, createdate) VALUES 
(
10000, --@SampleCount
'My Old Type Name', --@TypeName
24930, --@TypeID
'58585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858585858', --@Samples
0::BIT, --@Compressed
1301259616, --@TopicSessionID
'11/1/2017 10:03:07 AM', --@StartTimeUTC
'11/1/2017 10:03:08 AM', --@EndTimeUTC
--'11/1/2017 10:03:07 AM' --@CreateDate
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

   SET @I = @I + 1;
END
```

How can I make this more efficient to get the best insert performance?

Comment: dont commit on each row - it will already be 10x faster

Comment: why not `insert select ... from generate_series(1, 1000000)`?..

Comment: The problem is that this is not a bulk insert. This is inserting individually 1 row after 1 row. A bulk insert would be a single insert of the result of a query that returns a ton of rows.

Comment: @VaoTsun How do I make each query slightly different using the generate_series function?  In other words can I use the series numbers for my TypeID and TopicSessionID columns?

Comment: @runamuk0 surely - give several rows expected as example

Comment: 24930, --@TypeID
24931, --@TypeID
24932, --@TypeID
...